# Sudden FPS Drop in CSGO

Tags: technical-issues, counter-strike-global-offensive

I have been playing csgo for the past 2-3 months, it runs smoothly on my laptop without any problem, but just last week my fps suddenly dropped to around 18-22 in game, totally unplayable. I havent changed any settings in game or in my laptop. I tried reinstalling CSGO or reformatting my laptop, still nothing works. Can anyone please give me a solution to my problem?

Comment: Do you have any software running (chrome, skype etc.) while playing. i know that chrome can cause fps loss on DotA2

Comment: no, absolutely nothing, even the firewall....i turned off everything. before i used to play csgo while chrome was still running...and my fps was stable.

Comment: Do you notice that your laptop is getting any hotter than it used to while playing the game?

Comment: Yes, when i was playing csgo it usually gets pretty hot. but im not sure if i damaged my drive or not? help?

Comment: is it a constant 18-22 fps? or does it drop down low sometimes?  i know my game drops from around 200fps down to 30 when i'm in a very sunny area on some maps like logs, if that's your issue then you should lower your video settings in csgo.

Answer (score 3):

If your laptop is hot try to download and configure some fan control software like SpeedFan, then set the fans to run higher, it will help. Im using SpeedFan on my computer too.

Comment: This solution might work if your cpu's are configured to run slower when they are overheated. Simply keeping the laptop on a table, or dusting out the laptop might work too.

Comment: will this solution also work for macs? I play on a Macbook Pro 13" and it overheats after one game in comp.

Comment: @Neffer_23 Google is your best friend... but anyway, try this [http://www.crystalidea.com/macs-fan-control](http://www.crystalidea.com/macs-fan-control)

Comment: @Neffer_23 no problem mate:)

Answer (score 0):

Though I don't know what happens to cause this, I found a trick that works for me!

Try pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, and then go back in the game. This usually does the trick for me.

Please let me know if it worked/ didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the laptop with some canned air. Dust can sometimes block the vents and fans of laptops decreasing its cooling efficiency.